# Join two prometheus queries

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Im trying to join two prometheus queries where the goal is to find windows services which are on state *not running* and its start mode is *auto*

I have created the following query but no result:

```
windows_service_state{environment="test",state!="running"} / on(instance)  group_left(environment,job,name,operating_system) windows_service_start_mode{start_mode="auto",environment="test"}
```

and get the following exception:

"many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side"

any idea?

Comment: Are you looking for services that are `state!="running"` and `start_mode="auto"` at the same time? Or you want to merge list of `state!="running"`  with the list of  `start_mode="auto"` services?

Comment: Im looking for state!="running" and start_mode="auto"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with the following query

```
sum by (instance,name) (windows_service_state{,state!="running"} == 1) + on (instance,name) sum by (instance,name) (windows_service_start_mode{start_mode="auto"} == 1)
```